# Mosquitto: 2.0.x Persistent Client Subscription info not considered after SIGUP to broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, persist

Bug cleaned up after investigation on (Date 20th October 2023)

Setup Details:
I have a client timeSeriesPublisher acting as a publisher of Topic A.
Configuration Clean Session as True,
Messages sent with QOS 1 )

I have a client timeSeriesSubscriber acting as a subscriber of Topic A.
Clean Session False,
QOS1

1. When timeSeriesSubscriber ( which is acting as subscriber) disconnects, mosquito stores all the messages that are sent by client timeSeriesPublisher in the mosquitto.db as timeSeriesSubscriber to the message is not yet finished reading the message.
2. With timeSeriesSubscriber in disconnection state if the broker is restarted the subscription information of client timeSeriesSubscriber is found to be still remembered as the new messages from timeSeriesPublisher continued to be accumulated/stored in the mosquitto.db.

But if a SIGHUP is given to the broker after the restart the new messages from timeSeriesPublisher are found to be acknowledged but are not delivered to timeSeriesSubscriber after it returns back nor are stored in the mosquitto.db.

Reference:
This behavior is found to be not in line with definition of persistent client
"On connection, a client sets the "clean session" flag, which is sometimes also known as the "clean start" flag. If clean session is set to false, then the connection is treated as durable. This means that when the client disconnects, any subscriptions it has will remain and any subsequent QoS 1 or 2 messages will be stored until it connects again in the future. "

Simplified duplication Procedure: (Date 20th October 2023)

Please find the simplistic duplication procedure using mosquitto_sub, mosquitto_pub and mosquito.
The script runs the broker, subscriber and publisher and restarts them in a timely fashion to create the bug.

1. Sets up the environment, files
2. Brings up broker and subscriber
3. publishes a message
4. kills the subscriber
5. Kills the broker
6. Setup broker again
7. publishes a message
8. SIGHUP broker
9. Publishes around 4 messages
10. Setup subscriber
11. Kills broker and subscriber

The messages which are expected to be received by the subscriber after it changes its state from inactive to active are lost if the SIGHUP message is given to broker. We can notice that neither subscriber received the messages nor they are stored in the db.
If the step 8 is skipped then we notice that there is no issue.
[Script that creates the issue](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=getfile&id=43605&)

Comment: Can you please show us a debug level Mosquitto v2 log covering PQRS subscribing and dropping, ABCD publishing a message, the broker restart and PQRS reconnecting? (this will answer some other questions such as MQTT version). Note that "clean session" (MQTTv3) differs from "clean start" (MQTT v5).

Comment: Added additional details please review

Comment: Sorry - the logs you have provided are incomplete, specifically in `ModulesAlreadyRunningbeforeMosquitto.log` the first reference to `pqrs` is `1695807724: Client pqrs disconnected` (the first time we do see it connect is at `1695807948` when it is immediately send a queued message, the same happens in the other file at `1695808764`). I would suggest you try a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - test with `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` for a start - if that works then the issue is most likely something in your code.

Comment: This is running inside a docker container. At every startup of the container there is a configuration reload action for mosquito. When configuration reloaded at startup mosquitto is checking for clients which are connected in past and which are not yet connected to it after it started. pqrs lately discovered that the mosquito is active and  connected with mosquito 3 minutes after the mosquito was active.

Comment: "startup mosquitto is checking for clients" - I'm not clear what this means (Mosquitto will only initiate outbound connections if a bridge is configured). It's useful to know this is running under docker but that should make little difference as long as the database is persistent. Are you able to provide logs without the missing segments?

Comment: Thank you for following the thread closely.                                                               

1) 
I noticed that if Reloading configuration is done I see "Client is disconnected messages"

1695807934: Reloading config....
1695807934: Client pqrs disconnected.

2) Missing segments have lot of mqtt packets with identical data so I have deleted them for clarity. 

3) I will focus on minimilastic duplication procedure

Comment: After spending some time I noticed that issue is related to SIGHUP and added simplified duplication procedure in the link

Comment: Interesting - I can duplicate this. Based upon my testing it looks like you need both the `kill -9` and `kill -SIGHUP` (if you resubscribe between these operations then things work as expected). I'd suggest raising [an issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues) - having the script to duplicate the issue should make it easy to trace.